# Simple Thread Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, service

i copied the following example [Microsoft Thread Example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815804)

Which gives the code below
but i get an error on the line "this.progressBar1.Value = newval;" stating that "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

what could be the issue?
thanks
damo

**C# Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{         
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadTask));
        trd.IsBackground = true;
        trd.Start();
    }
    private void ThreadTask()
    {
        int stp;
        int newval;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            stp = this.progressBar1.Step * rnd.Next(-1, 2);
            newval = this.progressBar1.Value + stp;
            if (newval > this.progressBar1.Maximum)
                newval = this.progressBar1.Maximum;
            else if (newval < this.progressBar1.Minimum)
                newval = this.progressBar1.Minimum;
            this.progressBar1.Value = newval;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is the main thread");
    }
}
```

Comment: UI controls cannot be accessed from other threads, you will have to invoke it back on the UI thread

Comment: Simple: don't ever touch the UI (even to read values) from a background thread. And there is not such a thing as "simple thread issue" - that is an oxymoron

Comment: Also, very important: when the background thread invokes to the UI thread, it should finish as soon as possible so the UI thread can stay responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invoke new delegate:

```
    delegate void ThreadTaskDelegate();
    private void ThreadTask()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ThreadTaskDelegate del = new ThreadTaskDelegate(ThreadTask);
            this.Invoke(del, null);
        }
        else
        {
            int stp;
            int newval;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                stp = this.progressBar1.Step * rnd.Next(-1, 2);
                newval = this.progressBar1.Value + stp;

                if (newval > this.progressBar1.Maximum)
                    newval = this.progressBar1.Maximum;
                else if (newval < this.progressBar1.Minimum)
                    newval = this.progressBar1.Minimum;

                this.progressBar1.Value = newval;

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }


    }
```

Happy coding! :)

Comment: This is what op original code was also. Let him edit for his needs.

Comment: i used this code above and it works but the main form is locked out?

Comment: If you copied their code, I guess the answer is yes :) It's always better to understand the code rather just to copy it.

Comment: @Gregor Sorry for the tone of my comment!  I really meant that as a "note" or FYI.

Comment: @user1438082 - When you invoke to the UI thread, it is important to do all the work you need to do and then get out so the UI can continue responding to user input.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I strongly suggested to use some higher level techniques like [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) rather than using `Thread` class directly. Task classes not only easier to use, they're more effective, easier to compose and easier to avoid such issues that you faced recently.

The main issue with your code that you trying to update UI objects from non-UI threads. UI technologies (like Windows Forms or WPF) requires that only thread that creates an UI object will access to their properties.

To fix this you should marshal control from non-UI thread to UI thread. And there is a plenty of options to do this (but all of them only a syntactic sugar around concept called [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx)):

1. Use synchronization context directly:

.

```
// storing SynchronizationContext in the private field of your form
private SynchronizationContext _syncContext = SyncrhonizationContext.Current;

private void MethodFromTheSeparateThread()
{
  // Marshaling control to UI thread
  _syncContext.Post(d =>
            {
                // Put all your code that access UI elements here
            }, null);
}
```

1. Use `InvokeRequired`/`Invoke` as Gregor mentioned already
2. Use TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext

.

```
private void ImplementLongRunningOperation()
{
  int id;
  string name;
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    // our long-runing part. Getting id and name
    id = 42;
    name = "Jonh Doe";
  }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
       // Handling results from the previous task.
       // This callback would be called in UI thread!
       label1.Text = id.ToString();
       label2.Text = name;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext);
}
```

As I mentioned, last approach (using `Tasks`) is a preferable way if you're working on .NET 4.0+. This not only saves you from some low-level classes but also lead to more clear design because you can clearly separate separate steps like getting the data and processing them.

Answer (score 1):

The example is a poor one.  You must access controls in the thread in which they are created.  This is almost always the main UI thread.  (It is possible to have separate UI threads for different forms each with their own message pumps.  But don't worry about that right now.)

The background thread must use [Control.Invoke(Delegate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to change to the main UI thread before accessing Controls.  Then, when the UI work is done, get out of the UI thread as soon as possible.

For example:

```
private void ThreadTask()
{
    // This code runs in the background thread.
    while (true)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // In order to access the UI controls, we must Invoke back to the UI thread
            this.Invoke(new ThreadStart(SetRandomProgress));
        }
        else
        {
            // We are already in the UI thread, so we don't have to Invoke
            SetRandomProgress();
        }

        // Wait briefly.  This wait happens in the background thread.
        // During this time, the UI is still responsive, because it is not blocked.
        // You can verify this by tweaking the duration to something longer (say, 5000 ms).
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

private void SetRandomProgress()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int stp = this.progressBar1.Step * rnd.Next(-1, 2);
    int newval = this.progressBar1.Value + stp;
    if (newval > this.progressBar1.Maximum)
        newval = this.progressBar1.Maximum;
    else if (newval < this.progressBar1.Minimum)
        newval = this.progressBar1.Minimum;

    this.progressBar1.Value = newval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your code like this, your `progressBar` will be updated in the UI thread, Invoke a method that does access to the `progressBar` through delegate. Check the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadTask));
            trd.IsBackground = true;
            trd.Start();
        }
        private void ThreadTask()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                int randValue = rnd.Next(-1, 2);
                progressBar1.Invoke(new updater(UpdateProgressBar), new object[] {randValue});
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        private delegate void updater(int value);
        private void UpdateProgressBar(int randValue)
        {
            int stp = this.progressBar1.Step * randValue;
            int newval = this.progressBar1.Value + stp;
            if (newval > this.progressBar1.Maximum)
                newval = this.progressBar1.Maximum;
            else if (newval < this.progressBar1.Minimum)
                newval = this.progressBar1.Minimum;
            this.progressBar1.Value = newval;

        }
```